# What is the best way to check with Boto3 if an RDS instance already exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds

I use this code to build an RDS instance (PostgreSQL in my case) via CloudFormation:

```
cf_client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
template = open("my_rds.yaml", 'r').read()
cf_client.validate_template(TemplateBody=template)
stack_result = cf_client.create_stack(**params)

waiter = cf_client.get_waiter('stack_create_complete')
print("waiting for stack to be ready...")
waiter.wait(StackName=stack_name)
```

That works ok as long as the instance has not been already created. In the last case an exception will be thrown. What is a good way to manage this situation like build only if needed otherwise continue?
I know that it is possible check if an instance is already there using boto3's `describe_db_instances` or for some examples I found online, try/catch some exceptions. But I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: What a better way would be for you?

Comment: Not sure, because I have doubts about the Boto3 API. Maybe there is an already existent solution for it without trying to figure out a best way.

Comment: You could create a Lambda-backed **Custom Resource** in the template that checks and then returns a value for a Condition statement within the template (that says whether or not to build the database), but this is rather messy and would make it difficult to link to the existing RDS instance. Have you considered putting the Amazon RDS portion in a separate template, and then only running it when a new RDS instance is required?